# Spring boot Java JPA saveAll not saving all data

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to get some data from CSV file and then save it on start of the application. But when i run saveAll() of the repo it will save only up to 348 rows to the DB while the file has over 400 rows in. I can see in the debbuger that correct amount of data is passed to the saving method.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.demo")
public class DemoApplication {

    private final StationsServicesImpl stationsServices;

    public DemoApplication(StationsServicesImpl stationsServices) {
        this.stationsServices = stationsServices;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    public List<CsvStations> parseCSVToCSVStationsObject() throws IOException {
        Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("src/main/resources/stations.csv"));
        CsvToBean<CsvStations> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder(reader).withType(CsvStations.class).withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(false).build();
        List<CsvStations> csvStations = csvToBean.parse();
        return csvStations;
    }

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void onStartApp() throws IOException {
        List<StationsDAO> stations = parseCSVToCSVStationsObject().stream()
                    .map(s -> new StationsDAO(
                                Long.parseLong(s.getId()),
                                s.getName(),
                                s.getAdress(),
                                s.getKaupunki(),
                                s.getKapasiteet(),
                                s.getOperaattor(),
                                s.getX(),
                                s.getY()
                    )).collect(Collectors.toList());

        stationsServices.addStations(stations);
    }
}
```

the `addStations()` method inside has just basically .saveAll() of JpaRepository;

I've tried also to loop and use just the .save() method but still same thing and tried to change this too `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=100`.

Comment: 52 rows missing is pretty specific. Take a look at what is persisted in the database and the diff from your data and it might help tell you why. First guess is that spread sheets don't filter out duplicate rows - does it maybe have multiple rows with duplicated CsvStations.id values? For reference, save just takes the current data and merges it into the existing row if the IDs are duplicated - so the first data is overwritten by the last.

Comment: @Chris You are correct! Issue was that I set id of the entity with the csv's ids. Made new column for csv ids and let the entity generate auto ids and now it saves all of them.

Comment: I have the same issue, about 885 records for every 1000 written.